# Fade in Scale effect but for pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement the fade and scale effect shown here:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

but for a page (with width and height of 100% of the browser) not a modal.

How can I do that using jquery or css? I tried copying the code on the page but it works best for modals not for pages that have width and height of 100%.

On the page are elements with minimum width of 1024px.

Comment: Added fix for your `min-width` elements in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated the jsFiddle to show it containing elements that are at least 1024px.**

You'll want to put your entire page into a wrapper element, and then give it the animation class on DOM Ready.

The CSS will be something like:

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.page-wrapper{
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    transform:scale(0);
    opacity:0;
    transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;
}
.page-wrapper.fade-and-scale{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;
}
```

And the jQuery will be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-wrapper').addClass('fade-and-scale');
});
```

This solution has the benefit of:

- "Growing" from the centre of the page, and falling back gracefully on older browsers
- Falling back gracefully on older browsers
- Not animating any fundamental css properties (ie. width or height)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gk5c08rc/4/

Comment: the problem is on the page there are elements that have a minimum width of 1024px. so this doesn't work

Comment: @BrownKL Why do you say that? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: Here's my CSS, 
`.first-use-overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: -$headerHeight;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    transform:scale(0);
    opacity:0;
    transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease;

    &.fade-and-scale {
        transform:scale(1);
        opacity:1;
    }
}`

Comment: Nice proposition but it's actually *growing* from the center of the document, and not from the center of the window, which can look awkward when the page is quite long. I saw you tried to fix it giving a 100% height to the wrapper, but that prevents scrolling.

Comment: @Raoulito I'm not sure what you mean about scrolling. It certainly does not prevent scrolling. Although, you are correct that the element will grow from the centre of the document.

Comment: @BrownKL try adding overflow:hidden to the .first-use-overlay. What is it that is not working? It seems to work when I use those values in my jsFiddle.

Comment: @jairbow on the JSFiddles linked at the bottom of your answer, the page wrapper has the CSS property `height:100%;`. Which makes the page grow from the center, but prevent scrolling (check your JSFiddle)

Comment: @Raoulito That was easily adjusted with the overflow property. Updated my jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/rn8ho7wL/

Wrap your page in a wrapper, and set a smaller (or whichever style you like to go **FROM**) into the base styles for that wrapper. Add in a `transition-duration` property.

```
#wrapper {
  transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, define a class where you want the page to go **TO**. Styled the same way.

```
#wrapper.open {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And in your javascript file (assuming jQuery is loaded), simply apply the style.

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').addClass('open');
});
```

Bear in mind that CSS3 transitions are not supported by IE9 and below, and also require some `vendor prefixes` to be largely compatible. For using the transform, as described in another answer, apply the following:

```
  -webkit-transform: scale(0); /* Ch <36, Saf 5.1+, iOS, An =<4.4.4 */
  -ms-transform: scale(0); /* IE 9 */
  transform: scale(0);
```

---

### Edit:

The issue with the `min-width` can easily be solved by adding `overflow: auto` to your wrapper element.

https://jsfiddle.net/rn8ho7wL/2/

Comment: We almost did the exact same thing. Nice! I like my solution because it falls back nicely on older browsers by not quickly flashing from the small size to the full size. And also because it doesn't explicitly set any fundamental css properties like width or height. Also, it will scale from the centre, instead of the top-middle.

Comment: Your example is simple and works well, but considering it's only the wrapper that resizes, and not the inner elements, it would look weird when the wrapper *grows* with a lot of elements in it that don't.